# Combining Translucent and Volume Shaders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I would just like to know why when using both a translucent shader and a volume absorption shader the volume absorption shader will darken and color the look of the translucent shader. I understand it has something to do with the way the translucent shader works, but I would really like to understand exactly why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translucent shader gets power (brightness) from the light rays that enter the surface scatter inside and come through the material.

When the rays coming through the volume are absorbed by volume absorption, the translucent shader gets less energy and is darker.

The scattering is also an approximation and you will get much more accurate results with volume scatter or subsurface scattering shaders.